# Continuity assumption in Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, predictive-models

It is clear that in the case of neural-networks-based models, we rely on continuity assumption of the underlying function $f$ that we are trying to approximate with our network given the universal approximation t. What I'm wondering about is, for other ML algorithms (e.g. Random Forest), do we still rely on the assumption that small perturbations on the inputs would lead to small perturbations on the output?

Comment: Good question; if you look at the algo for building, say, Friedman's CART, you'll notice that it has a much more global (though axis-aligned) picture of what's going on than gradient-based methods do.

Comment: By construction, a decision tree is discontinuous, because the model induces dichotomous splits on the inputs.